# Use Singleton in Inner Class in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

Thanks for everyone because of helping me ^^ my problem is resolved !

I meet problem when I use Singleton in inner class using C++ language. Please help me and sorry for my bad English.

```
class A: public AA
{
    class InnerA
    {
        private:
            static InnerA* _innerA;
        public:
            ~InnerA();
            void Release();

            static InnerA* GetInstance()
            {
                if (_innerA == NULL)
                {
                    static InnerA static_instance;
                    _innerA = &static_instance;
                }
                return _innerA ;
            };
.....
```

The console show the below error after compiling :

```
undefined reference to `A::InnerA::_innerA'
```

I also modify like below code, but I still meet the above error.

```
class A: public AA
    {
        class InnerA
        {
            private:
                static InnerA* _innerA;
            public:
                ~InnerA();
                void Release();

                static InnerA* GetInstance()
                {
                    if (A::InnerA::_innerA == NULL)
                    {
                        static A::InnerA::_innerA static_instance;
                        _A::InnerA::_innerA = &static_instance;
                    }
                    return A::InnerA::_innerA;
                };
    .....
```

Please help me !!! Thanks very much

Comment: SideNote: First line of defense for singleton-logic. Ask yourself wtf am I doing using a singleton?

Comment: "I meet problem when I use Singleton" Yes, that's what usually happens.

Comment: Hi WhozCraig, 
In fact, I'm a Java guy. I'm a newbie in C++, so my knowledge in C++ is very little. Sorry for my silly question :)

Comment: @HienNguyen: In Java, singletons merely increase coupling, hide dependencies, and make (unit) testing unnecessarily difficult. In C++, they do all that, and also introduce horrendous lifetime-management issues; it's much better to avoid them.

Comment: Hi Mike Seymour, thanks for your explaination, I'm reading more about C++ to understand in depth.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Hi Peter Wood, I'm reading it. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All static data members of a class must be **defined** somewhere. Put the following into a .cpp file:

```
A::InnerA *A::InnerA::_innerA;
```

However, do you actually need that static pointer at all? You could just simplify your code like this:

```
class A: public AA
{
    class InnerA
    {
        public:
            ~InnerA();
            void Release();

            static InnerA* GetInstance()
            {
                static InnerA static_instance;
                return &static_instance;
            }
.....
```

Then, you wouldn't need any static member definitions.

Comment: Hi Angew,

Thanks for your concern and your help. I'm a newbie in C++, so I have some silly questions :(. Will the application create many static_instance or only one, if the OuterClass A calls GetInstance of InnerClass InnerA many times ?

Comment: Hi Angew, after debugging, I see it only creates one not many static_instance. Thanks for your help :) Have a nice day

Comment: Hi Angew, in your code will C++ delete static_instance automatically after finish the app ? Please help me one more time! Thanks for that :)

Comment: @HienNguyen When a function-local variable is declared as `static`, it gets *static storage duration* (the same as global variables get). This means it's destroyed at program termination, assuming it was ever initialised. If control never entered the function, the var was never initialised and will thus not be destroyed.

Comment: @HienNguyen And as you've already figured out, `static` variables of function scope are only ever initialised once. This applies even in the presence of multiple threads (at least since C++11).

Comment: I got it, thanks for your help, it's the first time I post a question in stackoverflow (in the past, I only search the question having similar problem with mine) and I see many people want to help me. Thank you and everyone.

Comment: @HienNguyen If one answer actually answers your question/solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted (by clicking the green tick mark next to it). That's how SO works.

Comment: @HienNguyen And, as one my professors always said, there's no stupid questions, only stupid answers :-) Your question was actually well-posed. If only all "first SO questions" were at least like this.

Comment: :) I see...and one more question how to type @ like you do.=> @HienNguyen. I can't do that +_+

Comment: @HienNguyen I don't quite understand. If you type '@' followed by a person's login name, SO will notify them (only one per post). If you start typing '@' and a name, it will offer a clickable pop-up autocomplete balloon of applicable names. A name is "applicable" if that person participated in comments to the question/answer already. ('@' is shift+2 on the English keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

First things first: you are conflating **two different** implementations of the Singleton pattern.

**Implementation 1**

The trusty leaky Singleton.

```
// Singleton.hpp
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& Instance() {
        if (I == nullptr) { I = new Singleton(); }
        return *I;
    }

private:
    Singleton();
    ~Singleton();

    static Singleton* I;
};

// Singleton.cpp
Singleton* Singleton::I = 0;
```

Two issues:

- leaks, unless you implement a *Release* and make sure to call it (once)
- not thread safe

**Implementation 2**

Known as Meyers' Singleton.

```
// Singleton.hpp
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& Instance() {
        static Singleton S;
        return S;
    }

private:
    Singleton();
    ~Singleton();
};
```

Main issue:

- subject to Destruction Order Fiasco (the equivalent to the [Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21732/))

You should pick either, but not mix the two.

Comment: Hi Matthieu, Thanks for your explanation and the related link, it's very helpful. However, I'm confused about Implementation 2, the variable S will be destroyed automatically by C++, won't it ?

Comment: Angew explained it for me in above comment, thanks for your help and sorry for not voting for your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @HienNguyen: Yes, that is the beauty of the implementation actually. The standard guarantees that all "globals" that were dynamically initialized will be destroyed in the reverse order in which they were created. Automatically. You can emulate this with Implementation 1 by using [`atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) to register a callback to be called during shutdown; it's the underlying mechanism if you do not want fancy things :)

Answer (score 0):

you have always define static data member. put this before main, just under your `class A` definition:

```
A::InnerA *A::InnerA::_innerA;
```

Answer (score 0):

In you class A implementation file you have to write something like\

```
A::InnerA *A::InnerA::_innerA;
```

to complete the definition of the member. In the header you only declare the member, but you don't define it.